# How to create a tags field for multiple Page classes in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

I want to add a field for keywords that almost every model in my site will have. It would be ideal if I didn't have to define a "TaggedPage" class for every Page model. So I created a BasePage abstract model but ParentalKey doesn't appear to work with an abstract model. How can I solve this?

I get this error:

```sh
home.TaggedPage.content_object: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'home.BasePage', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
home.TaggedPage.content_object: (fields.E307) The field home.TaggedPage.content_object was declared with a lazy reference to 'home.basepage', but app 'home' doesn't provide model 'basepage'.
```

home/models.py contains these models:

```py
class PageTag(TagBase):
    """ Tag used for the keywords meta html tag"""

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "search/meta keyword"
        verbose_name_plural = "search/meta keywords"


class TaggedPage(ItemBase):

    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        PageTag,
        related_name="tagged_pages",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    content_object = ParentalKey(
        to='home.BasePage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_items'
    )


class BasePage(MetadataPageMixin, Page):

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(
        through='home.TaggedPage',
        blank=True,
        help_text="Used for the keywords meta html tag",
    )

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
        FieldPanel('tags'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class HomePage(BasePage):
    parent_page_types = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point the ParentalKey at the `Page` model instead:

```
content_object = ParentalKey(
    to='wagtailcore.Page',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='tagged_items'
)
```

At the database level this will have the behaviour you're looking for: a foreign key field referencing the ID of the page object. The one minor side effect is that the `tagged_items` relation will be defined on all Page objects, not just ones inheriting from BasePage, but that shouldn't cause any problems.